# AS3. Controlling videos in separate childs

Tags: actionscript-3, video

Im having a bit of a problem with controlling videos. I have this `Main.as` where I'm adding a child. The child contains a video thats looping.

In Main.as i run this, which just adds the video. (video is in _idleView)

```
_idleView = new IdleView(this.stage);
addChild(_idleView);
```

My `IdleView.as` looks like this. This is the constructor which adds the video and loops it.

```
        _video = new Video();
        addChild(_video);

        _nc = new NetConnection();
        _nc.connect(null);
        _ns = new NetStream(_nc);

        _ns.client = _meta;
        _video.attachNetStream(_ns);
        _ns.play(Settings.VIDEO_URL + "idle.flv");
```

In `Main.as` i will later on add a new child (by click) also containing a video. Just like the idleView but no loop. Whenever that new child gets added i want to be able to play the idleView video to the end, stop it, and then let the new childs video start to play.

Don't know how to achieve this really. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `playVideo` function to `IdleView` that just plays the idle video without looping it, then call it in your `click` handler:

```
_newChild:ChildVideo;

private function click(e:Event):void {
    //other stuff
    //Set the new child video to the _newChild variable
    _idleView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onIdleVideoComplete);
    _idleView.playVideo();
}

private function onIdleVideoComplete(e:Event):void {
    _newChild.playVideo();
}
```

In `IdleView`:

```
public function playVideo():void {
    _video = new Video();
    addChild(_video);

    _nc = new NetConnection();
    _nc.connect(null);
    _ns = new NetStream(_nc);
    _ns.client = {};
    _ns.client.onPlayStatus = onPlayStatus;

    _ns.client = _meta;
    _video.attachNetStream(_ns);
    _ns.play(Settings.VIDEO_URL + "idle.flv");
}

private function onPlayStatus(item:Object):void {
    if (item.code == NetStream.Play.Complete) {
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736656/correctly-trap-onplaystatus-for-netstream and the [Adobe docs for NetStream and playStatus](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onPlayStatus)